# "Qu'est-ce qui nous dit que" or "Qui nous dit que", are these rhetoric questions?

Tags: sens

- Qu'est-ce qui nous dit que les plantes et les bactéries, elles aussi, ne sont pas sensibles.
- Qui nous dit que les plantes et les bactéries, elles aussi, ne sont pas sensibles.

Does these mean "On what grounds do you believe that ~~~" or "What makes you believe that ~~~" or "Who said that ~~~"?

Answer (score 2):

They are both rhetorical. There is no *vous* but *nous* in these sentences so by using "you believe", you aren't exactly matching the meaning which is more like:

> What would tell us (i.e. lead us to believe) that plants and bacterias aren't sentient too.

The second sentence says "Who tell us that..." but the meaning is equivalent.

An alternative translation might be:

> What states that plants and bacterias...

or

> Who states that plants and bacterias...

To answer to Emmanuel's comments, there is absolutely no doubt the question is rhetorical, i.e. a question that doesn't really expect an answer, especially a contradictory one, but is just used to make a point.

Here is the full sentence:

> [*Qu’est-ce qui nous dit que les plantes et les bactéries, elles aussi, ne sont pas sensibles (elles le sont d’ailleurs, d’une manière ou d’une autre, j’en suis persuadé) ?*](https://www.blog-les-dauphins.com/les-scientifiques-affirment-que-les-dauphins-devraient-etre-traites-comme-des-personnes-non-humaines-article-du-times/)

Comment: the exact meaning would be : what proves to us...

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO To prove (*prouver, démontrer*) is stronger than *dire*.

Comment: In that context however, that's what it means. You can't suppose that a correct answer to this question would be a false statement.

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO Not sure about what you mean with "a false statement" but the expected answer to this rhetorical question is *rien*.

Comment: It's rien if, and only if, nothing proves/says/shows it. Otherwise, any answer can come : see https://goo.gl/PXz3fR or https://goo.gl/eE4ehW

Comment: How about translating this expression into "How could we be sure that ..."?

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO Contrairement au lien proposé, il s'agit ici d'une question rhétorique. Un réponse contradictoire n'est pas attendue par son auteur.

Comment: @Alone-zee To be sure looks also stronger than what is conveyed by *nous dire*. If I tell you something, neither do I prove it nor do you necessarily trust me.

Comment: @jiliagre, Qu'est ce qui nous prouve que les plantes etc ? Egalement réthorique. Quand on dit _qu'est ce qui nous dit que_, que ce soit réthorique ou non, on met en doute ce qui est communément admis ou qui semble aller de soi, ce qui veut dire que l'on demande (qu'on ait la réponse dans le cas réthorique, ou non dans les autres cas) si on peut en être sûr, donc la traduction de Alone-zee me parait bonne, ce qui revient à demander si quelquechose le prouve. Mais on ne fait pas des maths, nos avis peuvent diverger.

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO Si tu penses qu'il n'y a pas de nuance entre *dire* et *affirmer*, nos avis divergent, en effet.

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO I agree with you there. It seems to me that the verb "dire" here is more than just about ***saying*** : "Qu'est-ce qui nous dit (***au-delà de tout doute raisonnable***) que ..." = "How can we know for sure that ..."